# How do I set label text size in Altair?

Tags: python, python-3.x, altair

I'm visualizing some data with Altair, and want to put labels on my chart. I've used https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_with_labels.html as an example.

I want to adjust the size of my points but not the size of the label text.

From the link above:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    'y': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    'label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
})

points = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q'
)

text = points.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=7
).encode(
    text='label'
)

points + text
```

This works as expected.

However, if I want to vary the size of my points to show additional information, in the `points` block I adjust so it now reads:

```
x='x:Q',
y='y:Q'
size='x'
)
```

Unfortunately we now also have text size that increases with `x`. Argh!

Setting a `size` command inside the `text` block doesn't override the text size as I expect it to. The axis configuration suggestions from [How do you set Axis FontSize in Altair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401693/how-do-you-set-axis-fontsize-in-altair) have not solved my problem. If I use `configure_text` from https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html#altair.Chart.configure_text I get: `ValueError: Objects with "config" attribute cannot be used within LayerChart. Consider defining the config attribute in the LayerChart object instead.` and don't know where to go next.

How can I get the text to stay the same size while the mark size changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `text = points.mark_text()`, the `text` layr inherits everything you defined in the `points` layer: here, that includes the `size` encoding.

If you do not want the `text` layer to have a size encoding, you can specify it only for the `points` layer. For example, you could do something like this:

```
points = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    size='x'
)

text = alt.Chart(source).mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=7
).encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    text='label'
)

points + text
```

The reason setting `size` in the `mark_text()` block doesn't override this is because encodings always supersede mark properties. See https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#global-config-vs-local-config-vs-encoding for more information on this.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I get that `text` inherits from `points`; I am surprised that it isn't overwritten by new values to the same variable.

Comment: See my edit at the bottom with more information on this.